# camera X Cancelled by another startFocusAndMetering

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camerax

I'm implementing a custom camera using cameraX library. I'm working on focusing and I did below things

```
viewFinder.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            return@setOnTouchListener when (event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    true
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                   // The below code is for focusing 

                    val factory = SurfaceOrientedMeteringPointFactory(
                        viewFinder.width.toFloat(),
                        viewFinder.height.toFloat()
                    )
                    val point = factory.createPoint(event.x, event.y)
                    try {
                        val action = FocusMeteringAction.Builder(point, FocusMeteringAction.FLAG_AF)
                            .apply {
                                disableAutoCancel() //focus only when the user tap the preview
                            }.build()

                        val future = cameraControl?.startFocusAndMetering(action)
                        future?.addListener(Runnable {
--->line 66                 val result = future?.get()
                            println("log result ---> $result")
                        }, cameraExecutor)

                    } catch (e: CameraInfoUnavailableException) {
                        println("log error ---> $e")
                    }
                    true
                }
                else -> false // Unhandled event.
            }
        }
```

Now, It is some what focusing the point I touched and it's not too accurate but it's ok. And while focusing after 5 to 6 times the app was crashing and closing.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-2-thread-1
...
...
java.lang.Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: androidx.camera.core.CameraControl$OperationCanceledException: Cancelled by another startFocusAndMetering()
...
...
...MainActivity$onCreate$2$1.run(MainActivity.kt:66)
```

I'm not getting why it's crashing and it is not frequently crashing. Sometimes it will crash and some times not.

Edit 1 :-

I got to know that when I tap focus multiple times this is happening. So, before start of focusing I need to clear the previous focus if in progress. But, how to clear previous focus I'm not getting.

Edit 2 :-

I tried this  `cameraControl?.cancelFocusAndMetering()`, I just put it at first line of try block. but still problem exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just removed This block

```
future?.addListener(Runnable {
          val result = future?.get()
          println("log result ---> $result")
       }, cameraExecutor)
```

and it's working fine. But I don't know is it right or wrong.

If anyone knows? please answer. currently I'm marking this as answer as it worked.

Comment: When you call `CameraControl.startFocusAndMetering()`, if a previous metering action is still running, it is cancelled. The future is cancelled and fails with the exception you're seeing in logcat. You shouldn't worry about it. Calling `CameraControl.cancelFocusAndMetering()` does the same thing, it cancels any ongoing metering actions, but with a slightly different error message, which you may have noticed.

Comment: @HusaynHakeem Thank you, But when I put the `future?.addListener` the app was crashing and closing even when I put that in try catch. Can you show me some code on how to handle it.

Comment: Is the app crashing because of the snippet in your answer (`future?.addListener(...)`)? For a code example, take a look at [this sample](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:camera/integration-tests/viewtestapp/src/main/java/androidx/camera/integration/view/PreviewViewFragment.java;l=333?q=PreviewViewFragment&ss=androidx).

Comment: @HusaynHakeem Yes, When the app crashed it always point's to the line `val result = future?.get()`.

Comment: I've also been experiencing this - wish I could know if the focus was successful or not!

Answer (score 3):

Apologies for the java code here. But from my experience the future?.get() needs to be wrapped in a try, catch

```
future.addListener(() -> {

    try
        {
            FocusMeteringResult result = (FocusMeteringResult) future.get();
            if(result.isFocusSuccessful())
            {
                // Focus has succeeded
            }
            else
            {
                // Focus has failed
            }
        }
        catch (ExecutionException e) // Thrown exceptions
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) // Thrown exceptions
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned the problem is due to future?.addListener. To solve this you can define the future variable outside the viewFinder.setOnTouchListener as:

```
private var future: ListenableFuture<FocusMeteringResult>? = null
```

and before calling the startFocusAndMetering(action) cancel the future

```
future?.cancel(true)
```

So your final code would look something like this:

```
private var future: ListenableFuture<FocusMeteringResult>? = null

viewFinder.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            return@setOnTouchListener when (event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    true
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                   
                    future?.cancel(true)

                    // The below code is for focusing 

                    val factory = SurfaceOrientedMeteringPointFactory(
                        viewFinder.width.toFloat(),
                        viewFinder.height.toFloat()
                    )
                    val point = factory.createPoint(event.x, event.y)
                    try {
                        val action = FocusMeteringAction.Builder(point, FocusMeteringAction.FLAG_AF)
                            .apply {
                                disableAutoCancel() //focus only when the user tap the preview
                            }.build()

                        future = cameraControl?.startFocusAndMetering(action)
                        future?.addListener(Runnable {
--->line 66                 val result = future?.get()
                            println("log result ---> $result")
                        }, cameraExecutor)

                    } catch (e: CameraInfoUnavailableException) {
                        println("log error ---> $e")
                    }
                    true
                }
                else -> false // Unhandled event.
            }
        }
```